# turning a collections counter into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, collections

I have a collection outcome resulting from the function:

```
Counter(df.email_address)
```

it returns each individual email address with the count of its repetitions.

```
Counter({nan: 1618, 'store@kiddicare.com': 265, 'testorders@worldstores.co.uk': 1})
```

what I want to do is to use it as if it was a dictionary and create a pandas dataframe out of it with two columns one for email addresses and one for the value associated.

I tried with:

```
dfr = repeaters.from_dict(repeaters, orient='index')
```

but i got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Counter' object has no attribute 'from_dict'
```

It makes thing that Counter is not a dictionary as it looks like. Any idea on how to append it to a df?

Comment: `from_dict` is a class method of DataFrames, not dictionaries/Counters. You could try: `dfr = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(repeaters, orient='index')`

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: @ajcr , I was just going to answer that.

Comment: @omri_saadon: do feel free to provide an answer if you'd like; comments are generally less useful so I'm happy to delete mine if an answer appears.

Comment: A counter is a subclass of dict and can be turned into a regular dict with dict(counter), see https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Why don't you just use `df.email_address.value_counts()`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
d = {}
cnt = Counter(df.email_address)
for key, value in cnt.items():
    d[key] = value
```

**EDIT**

Or, how @Trif Nefzger suggested:

```
d = dict(Counter(df.email_address))
```

Answer (score 2):

as ajcr wrote at the comment, `from_dict` is a method that belongs to dataframe and thus you can write the following to achieve your goal:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

repeaters = Counter({"nan": 1618, 'store@kiddicare.com': 265, 'testorders@worldstores.co.uk': 1})

dfr = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(repeaters, orient='index')
print dfr
```

**Output:**

```
testorders@worldstores.co.uk     1
nan                           1618
store@kiddicare.com            265
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use `pd.Series.value_counts`, which returns a `Series` object.

```
df.email_address.value_counts(dropna=False)
```

Sample output:

```
b@y.com    2
a@x.com    1
NaN        1
dtype: int64
```

This is not exactly what you asked for but looks like what you'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why there are many convoluted ways.

1. `Counter` is a `dict` subclass. So you can pass to anything that expects a param of type `dict`.

```
class Counter(dict):
    '''Dict subclass for counting hashable items...
```

2. If you really really want to convert `Counter` to a `dict`:

```
>>> d1 = dict(cntr)
>>> d1
{nan: 1618, 'store@kiddicare.com': 265, 'testorders@worldstores.co.uk': 1}
>>> 
>>> 
>>> d2 = {k: v for k, v in cntr.items()}
>>> d2
{nan: 1618, 'store@kiddicare.com': 265, 'testorders@worldstores.co.uk': 1}
>>>
```

3. To create a Pandas `DataFrame` from `Counter` use [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html). It takes a `dict`, but a dict of either:

   - `{'col_name1': [r1c1, r2c1...], 'col_name2': [r1c2, r2c2,...], ...` OR
   - `{'row_id1': [r1c1, r1c2,...], 'row_id2': [r2c1, r2c2,...], ...`

where `rNcM` is the value `Nth` row and `Mth` column.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> cntr = Counter({float('nan'): 1618, 'store@kiddicare.com': 265, 'testorders@worldstores.co.uk': 1})
>>> cntr
Counter({nan: 1618, 'store@kiddicare.com': 265, 'testorders@worldstores.co.uk': 1})
>>> 
>>> import panadas as pd
>>> pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'emails': cntr.keys(), 'repeatation_count': cntr.values()})
>>> print(pdf.to_string())
                         emails  repeatation_count
0                           NaN               1618
1           store@kiddicare.com                265
2  testorders@worldstores.co.uk                  1
>>>
```