# Turn dictionaries inside a pandas column into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `Dataframe` which looks like this:

```
    cus_id          cat_counts
0   4462            {'LOUNGE': 2}
1   5482            {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 2, 'SMALL APPLIANCES': 1}
2   8101            {'BEDDING': 1, 'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 1}
3   3388            {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 1, 'BEDROOM SUITES': 1}
5   3030            {'ACCESSORIES': 1, 'VISUAL': 2, 'MAJOR APPLIANCES' : 2}
6   8942            {'VISUAL': 1, 'AUDIO': 1, 'BEDDING': 1}
7   5775            {'ACCESSORIES': 2, 'VISUAL': 1}
8   5489            {'ACCESSORIES': 1, 'KITCHENWARE': 1, 'BEDDING' : 1
9   9370            {'ACCESSORIES': 1, 'VISUAL': 2, 'MAJOR APPLIANCES' : 5}
10  5936            {'KITCHENWARE': 1, 'ACCESSORIES': 4, 'VISUAL': 3}
11  3854            {'ACCESSORIES': 1, 'VISUAL': 2}
12  4016            {'LOOSE CARPETING': 1, 'BEDDING': 1}
13  3503            {'HOME OFFICE': 2}
```

I would like to convert the `cat_counts` column into seperate columns joined to the main dataframe with the `key`s being the columns and the `value`s being the counts in the column. Here's an example (some columns have been omitted for space):

```
    cus_id         LOUNGE | MAJOR APPLIANCES | SMALL APPLIANCES | BEDDING | BEDROOM SUITES | ACCESSORIES
0   4462              2           0                  0               0           0               0
1   5482              0           2                  1               0           0               0
2   8101              0           1                  0               1           0               0  
3   3388              0           1                  0               0           1               0
5   3030              0           2                  0               0           0               1
6   8942              0           0                  0               1           0               0 
7   5775              0           0                  0               0           0               2
8   5489              0           0                  0               1           0               1
9   9370              0           5                  0               0           0               1
10  5936              0           0                  0               0           0               4
11  3854              0           0                  0               0           0               1
12  4016              0           0                  0               1           0               0
13  3503              0           0                  0               0           0               0
```

I have tried `df['cat_counts'].apply(lambda a: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a))` but i get an error
`If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`. I've checked this question 
[Transform a Counter object into a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111032/transform-a-counter-object-into-a-pandas-dataframe) &
[turning a collections counter into dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807945/turning-a-collections-counter-into-dictionary/31808609)
but they don't answer my question. I don't know if this is even possible. All I know is you can create a `Dataframe` from a dictionary. If there is a **stackoverflow** post regarding this please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If performance is not important convert each dict to `Series` and replace missing values to `0`:

```
df['cat_counts'].apply(lambda a: pd.Series(a)).fillna(0)
```

For improve performance convert column to `DataFrame`:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['cat_counts'].tolist()).fillna(0)
```

All together with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for add original columns:

```
df1 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('cat_counts').tolist()).fillna(0).astype(int))
```

---

Comment: @jezrael, First of all Greetings sir!! I would like to THANK you for your all GREAT solutions and explanations(I try to follow you and wonder often how Good you are and how you become this much Great in Pandas :) ), just a request when you write your own book for Pandas, lemme know then I will be the first person to buy it :) :) GOD bless you, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this in pandas is using `json_normalize`:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
json_normalize(df.cat_counts)
```

And to join:

```
pd.concat([df, json_normalize(df.cat_counts)])
```

Comment: @jezrael 's answer worked. However I want to try this one as well. Thank you for your reply